# time.Now() timestamp adds 000 at the end

Tags: go

I need a timestamp to sign an API call but `time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()` adds 000 to every timestamp, I have the same code running in node.js and the timestamp has the expected format there, I'm new to Golang so maybe it's not related to time but more to casting types

```
timestamp := time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()
fmt.Printf("%d", timestamp)
```

outputs

```
1612732021943204000
```

when

```
let timestamp = new Date().getTime();
console.log(timestamp);
```

outputs

```
1612732021943204
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is only 3 zeros? It should be 6.

Javascript `Date.getTime()` retuns milliseconds. Go `time.UnixNano()` returns nanoseconds. If you divide the number by 1000000, you can get the millisecond value.

Comment: When I compared the node js and the go results I had nearly always the same results except for 000 at the end of the go one, I'm using `fmt.Sprintf("%d")` to create my post url so maybe that has some effect on the missing 000

Comment: thanks I think this is the correct answer, so there's just no ms in Golang ?

Comment: No, if you need ms, multiply ns with 1000000

Answer (score 1):

The first value 1612732021s_943m_204u_000n is clearly in ns. The second 1612732021s_943m_204u is in micro seconds.
The 000ns part is likely due to insufficient resolution, so merely setting the scale to ns.